# How to sort strings alphabetically that separated by special character like comma in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, string, linq

In C#, how can I sort strings that separated by special character, like ","

For example I have string like this

```
string sStates="IA,KY,CT,ME,AZ";
```

How can I re-sort them alphabetically like

```
"AZ,CT,IA,KY"
```

Split them in an Array will work.

But is there a more effective way?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What would you consider "more effective"? What are your metrics? The technique you describe works and is only 3 lines of code (and can be reduced to 1 if you really want to go hog wild).

Comment: More effective than a correct solution?  More effective *how*?

Comment: you can not do without making any kind of array/collection

Comment: Why are you working with delimited strings in the first place? Any collection would do better in most cases.

Comment: Can you show us the "split them into an array" code that you are referring to?  It is hard to say if there is a *more effective* way to code something when we cannot see what we're comparing against.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done within a single line of code using linq:

```
var result = string.Join(",", source.Split(",").OrderBy(s => s));
```

Efficiency considerations should not apply here unless you're doing this for huge strings (or a hugh number of strings) under a tight timeline, or having an actual performance problem.

Readable code is far better then fast code.

As a rule - **You should design your code for clarity, not for performance.** Write code that conveys the algorithm it is implementing in the clearest way possible. Set performance goals and measure your code's performance against them. If your code doesn't measure to your performance goals, Find the bottle necks and treat them. Don't go wasting your time on nano-optimizations when you design the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this simple way

```
var orderedString = source.Split(",").OrderBy(p => p);
var result = string.Join(",", orderedString);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a fan of using Lists in .Net personally.

```
using System.Linq;

var sStates = "IA,KY,CT,ME,AZ";
var orderedList = sStates.Split(',').ToList().OrderBy(o => o);
var orderedString = string.Join(",", orderedList.ToArray());
```

Comment: The result the OP requested was a string, not a list or an IEnumerable...

Comment: There is no point to using `.ToList()` in the middle of the linq expression like that.  Maybe at the *end*, though the desired result is a `string`.

Comment: The `ToArray` is equally unnecessary